# Synonyms of "comes with a lag"

Tags: synonyms

Could you provide synonym expressions of **"comes with a lag"** as used below? This is a recurrent expression in my studies. I am not sure if it is correct. I have found it in certain sources. I would like to formulate it better and in different ways to enrich my essays. I have thought as well about "acts with a lag" and "works with a lag". Cheers.

> The adjustment of the economy to central bank decisions **comes with a lag**.

Comment: Are you aware that you can use "lag" as a verb (or "lag behind").

Comment: @StuartF: Could you explain how would you use these alternatives in the example? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use: *"comes with a delay"*

You could also rephrase it:

*"always involve a lag"*

*"always come with a delay"*

Also, if you are talking about a particular adjustment, the sentence should be in either the past or future tense.

"An adjustment to the economy to reflect central bank decisions will come with a lag/delay"

"The adjustment to the economy reflecting central bank decisions came after a lag/delay"

Comment: Do you think that "comes with a lag" or "comes with a delay" are fully idiomatic in the context of the example sentence? Or are they somewhat awkward? I have used the translator for both to my native language and they both sound awkward in my native language, but maybe in English they are OK.

Comment: I don't think they are ideal, as the sentence stands. I would recast it as (for example): "adjustment**s** to the economy *as a result of* central bank decisions *always/tend to* come *after* a lag". There are other equally good reworkings.

Comment: Thanks. You are the native expert and my opinion is of little relevance, but your reworked sentence seems to me longer, more complicated, and with a worse flow? Isn't the rule in English to make it as short as possible?

Comment: It's difficult to explain, but your original sentence had a couple of problems, and correcting those caused the sentence to get longer by ~25%. For example, "adjust the economy to a decision", is not natural English. Sorting that out is where most of the extra words came from. I fell the revised sentence flows well, but you'd need to get the opinion of other native speakers to confirm or deny that.

Comment: Could I ask what the second problem was? Thanks

Comment: I see that you are also sometimes using "comes after a lag" instead of "comes with a lag". Is "after" preferable to "with"? Or are both equally fine?

Comment: They are both OK, but 'after' is more accurately descriptive of what's happening. I would always use delay if the sentence is cast this way. If using 'lag' I'd say: *"adjustments to the economy lag the central bank decisions that cause them"*

Comment: Then maybe just keep it simple and use "the adjustment [...] **takes some time**" instead of the seemingly problematic "comes with a lag/delay"?

Comment: It's hard for me to get why "a delay" is preferable to "a lag". To me, "a delay" conveys the idea of "being late" or "postponing something", which is not exactly appropriate to the situation, whereas "a lag" conveys the more neutral and simple idea of a mere "period of time between two events", which seems more appropriate to the situation. Does it make sense?

Comment: Lag is perfectly good, but delay is by no means more negative. You can quite safely use either.

Comment: Could we sum it all up with a ranking of all the provided alternatives, clearly stating their degree of appropriateness or imperfection? There are many answers and some are confusing because an alternative is criticised in a message, but then another message says that such an alternative is fine. Thank you so much.

Comment: That's not really possible, because every English user will have their own personal opinion. I don't want to make any very definite statement on something which another native speaker might have a contradictory opinion. Sorry not to be able to be more helpful.

Comment: OK, I understand it. My conclusion is that all the alternatives that we have proposed are valid and that it is a matter of style, in spite of some messages stating that some alternatives are imperfect. I have found instances of all alternatives in books.

Comment: How about changing the order in the original sentence? **The adjustment of the economy comes with a lag to central bank decisions.** I guess that this would solve the problem with "adjusting to a decision", which you said was not natural.

Answer (score 0):

In economics, you would often encounter this written as

> The key economic indicators *lag* central bank decisions.

As @stuart-f has mentioned in the comment, "lag" is used as a verb here.